# what is the difference between remote functionality and non remote in react-bootstrap-table

Tags: reactjs

hei everyone,

I'm trying to work with the react-bootstrap-table, but I couldn't understand what is the remote table for ?

While navigating in the github examples, I have noticed that most people are using the remote functionality, but I think that both of them (remote and non remote) can do the same thing , so what is the difference ?? and which one is the best to use and why ?

Please help me if you know the answer,
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is the explanation](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/docs.html#remote) from `react-bootrstrap-table` documentation.

Basically, when you are using the default table (with the `remote` prop set to false by default) the library does all the "dirty" state-mangement work - like sorting and filtering the data - for you, under the hood.

When you set this property to `true` it becomes your resposibilty to handle and manipulate how the table will react to your data. You can handle these data manipulations with a state management framework like [redux](https://redux.js.org/) or [mobx](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx), with a parent Component's state - or with api calls to a server and use `react-bootrstrap-table`'s hooks (`onSortChange`, `onPageChange`, etc.) in order to trigger events that will fetch or manipulate your data.

In short - if you are looking for the basic simple implementation of `react-bootrstrap-table` - you can probably stick with the default setup and not set `remote` to true.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation that was really useful for me, so please , if I need to manage the data in my mongo database (insert a new row, delete and update) , will it be enough to use the default table or do I must use the remote one ?

Comment: It sound from what you are describing that you **will** need to use the `remote={true}` prop - since you want actions in your table to affect the data you have stored in mongo (add row, delete row, etc. ). Hope this makes sense..